# sqoop : I am pulling data from sqoop to hdfs.the default delimiter is <tab> . How can I give a custom delimiter?

Tags: apache, sqoop

I'm able to my mysqlimport do the right things with the `--fields-terminated-by '\001' --lines-terminated-by '\002'` options, however, Sqoop still things that `\n` is the right record separator character.

Comment: please ignore the content.

Comment: this is the real question :

Comment: sqoop : i am pulling data from sqoop to hdfs.the default delimited is <tab> . how can i give a custom delimiter ?